# Livewire-JS scripts conflict

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have an issue with the livewire and the CKEditor script load. Currently, I have a modal for creating some kind of the post and in there I have a few checkboxes on which click I need to show/hide something. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the "Extended description" checkbox I should get something like this:

[image]

But since users have an option for default images or to upload some, after the click on the "Use default images" checkbox my ckeditor script crashes:

[image]

**In the livewire I am using dispatchBrowserEvent like:**

```
public function render()
{
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent("reload-ckeditor");
    return view('modal.service-modal');
}
```

**And then in the blade:**

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'extended-description', {
        customConfig: '{{ asset('js/ckeditor.js') }}'
    } );
    window.addEventListener('reload-ckeditor', function() {
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'extended-description', {
            customConfig: '{{ asset('js/ckeditor.js') }}'
        } );
    })
</script>
```

**Important thing to mention:** *this is the multistep form so on the step increase/decrease scripts crash, too*

If you need any more parts of the code write me in the comment :)

Comment: I had to build a multistep form like this in the past. This route that you're taking it will be very difficult to maintain; I would recommend you to bind the CKEditor in an alpine component, this way the livewire requests will not crash your instance.
Also, as an additional tip, depending on the size and complexity of your page it may be good to rely on alpine to do these interactions, the page it's more fluid when you load everything and only hide/show using javascript.

Comment: @itepifanio Thanks, I will definitely start working with alpine then. Was thinking about it for a while now.